# Find height for every block in given area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to find height for every block in given area (several hundred/thousands blocks).

Here is example:
[image]

It's 2x2 area and I can do it manually and we get: 3 blocks with `68` height and 1 block with `69` height but in high scale 1000x1000 for example it would take ages to do it manually.

Is there any tools/mods/anything to do that?

I need it to find best height to start flattering area.

Comment: What do you actually want? A numerical display, storing it in a file or something, a gradient picture, …? Also, should e.g. flowers, water, etc. count? What about bottom slabs? Are you only interested in the top block in each column or also the floor of caves below?

Comment: Pretty basic, I need it only to help me consider in what height I should start flatten area where I gonna build something. So if there 8k blocks with 68 height out of 10k blocks in total it's obviously easier and faster to make all blocks in that area 68 in height. Hope that makes sense. They way to output data is not strict. flowers, water, etc doesn't necessary matter same goes to slabs. Just a top.

Comment: In a chunk inside a region file, there is `Level.Heightmaps` with 4 lists inside and `Level.Sections[].SkyLight`, which are lists, but all five have weird formats.

Comment: This question would really benefit for the desired output format. Without it, I feel like this on a knife's edge to being put on hold for details/clarity.

Comment: @Gigazelle There are already two such votes on it and I voted for it and then undid that after the asker's comment. But apparently what I interpreted was wrong (see comments under my answer), so the real answer would be "you can't fully analyse an entire area automatically in Survival", which is a pretty uninteresting answer/question, because of course you can't, otherwise finding stuff would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the entire area somewhere else using `/clone` and then use this command on the copied area:

```
/execute store result score @s <scoreboard_name> run fill <lower_coords> <higher_coords> air
```

… with `<scoreboard_name>`, `<lower_coords>` and `<higher_coords>` replaced with the corresponding parts.

This stores the number of blocks there are in the area (above a certain height, if you start cloning higher up) in the scoreboard. If you just want the number displayed in text, you can also just run `/fill <lower_coords> <higher_coords> air`.

Comment: oh sorry didn't realize I was that unclear. I would just use world edit if I could, but I need to do it survival server where I don't have OP perms.

Comment: Then… count? What else would you expect? You can't automatically analyse an entire area in Survival, because it's partially the point of Survival that you don't know everything.

Answer (score 0):

If the height difference between lowest and highest isn't huge, [Litematica](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/litematica) may come in handy. It's a client-side mod and doesn't require server's "cooperation". Select the area you want to analyze, then flatten the selection to 1 layer, and save schematic of each layer (or as subregions of a schematic). Then use the "Material list" to write down a total number of blocks of each layer. Obviously this gives you also blocks that aren't top-most, but you can get a good approximation count of "surface" blocks (off by areas of overhangs and shallow caves) by subtracting the count of blocks in layer above "current".